# Dividing by arbitrary numbers using shifting operators

Tags: c++, bit-shift

How can you divide a number `n` for example by `24` using shifting operators and additions?

(`n % 24 == 0`)

Comment: For an ACM ICPC problem where I need to operate with 128-bit numbers (and therefore have to do it manually). Shifting and adding is not very hard to perform manually.

Comment: The code you show calculates a single boolean, and actually has very little to do with divsion. cosider that 24 is binary 11000. Now it is obvious that 11011000 % 11000 == 0. 11011000 = 11000000 + 11000, and 11000000 % 11000 == 0 and 110000 % 11000 == 0. This can be generalized to a test `(x % N ==0 )` where N is a constant.

Comment: it just says that n is divisible by 24 and therefore I don't need some numbers after the decimal point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works by first finding the highest bit of the result, and then working back.

```
int div24(int value) {
  // Find the smallest value of n such that (24<<n) > value
  int tmp = 24;
  for (int n = 0; tmp < value; ++n)
    tmp <<= 1;
  // Now start working backwards to find bits of the result. This is O(i).
  int result = 0;
  while(value != 0) {
    tmp >>= 1;
    result <<= 1;
    if (value > tmp) { // Found one bit.
       value -= tmp; // Subtract (24<<i)
       result++;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Example:

```
Value = 120 :  n = 2
Step 0: tmp = 96, result = 0, value = 24, result = 1
Step 1: tmp = 48, result = 2
Step 2: tmp = 24, result = 4, value = 0, result = 5
```

Answer (score 4):

The pencil-and-paper algorithm for the division uses only "shifts" (base 10 shifts) and subtractions. You can do exactly the same thing in base 2.

Sorry I can't find a link for the algorithm, but you should have learnt it as a child.

EDIT: actually since additions are cheap, you don't have to try to extract the correct digits  one by one, so you can simplify the algorithm a bit...

Assuming positive dividend and divisor...

Take the power of two immediately larger than the divisor (here, 32).

It is easy to divide your number by this power of two. Say the division produces `k1`.
Subtract `k1*24` from the number (call the rest `r1`) and iterate...

When you have obtained `k1`, `k2`, ... `kn` numbers and the rest `rn` no longer contains 32, do a last check to see if `rn` contains 24.

The result of the division is `k1+k2+...+kn (+1 if 24 fits in rn)`.

Comment: Note that this algorithm handle gracefully the special case where you are dividing by a power of two: in this case it converges in one step. It can take a logarithmic number of subtractions/additions if the divisor is a power of two plus one.

Comment: 240/32 = 7; 240-32*7=16 which is < 24. desired result is 10. doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @int3, Etan: In order to be a simplified version of the pencil-and-paper algorithm, the "k1*32" should of course be read "k1*24". I edited the answer to fix it.

Comment: The reason it works is that k1, .., kn are all the times 24 has been removed from the dividend before arriving to a rest that didn't contain 24.

Answer (score 1):

```
int
div24(int value) {
   int result = 0;
   while (value >= 24) {       
      int accum = 24;
      int tmp = 1;    
      while (accum + accum <= value) {
         accum += accum;
         tmp += tmp;
      }
      value -= accum;     
      result += tmp;
   }   
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Using two loops? You're testing repeatedly to find the highest value of tmp such that `(24 << tmp) < value` but every time you find such a factor, you restart `tmp` at 1.

Comment: sorry, you're algorithm is of course faster, this was the first thing that came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no doubt a clever hack for 24, using shift operators [and/or subtractions] only really makes sense for powers of 2. Even then, its far more likely to confuse readers than it is to generate more efficient code with a modern compiler.

Comment: Oh... Do you think the question was about a *clever* way? Well that changes everything... :)

Comment: @Pascal: Without the explanation, it all sounds very homeworky. Nice answer by you, +1